# ImageMagick path fill

Tags: svg, imagemagick

I am trying to convert an SVG image to a PNG using the latest version of ImageMagick (6.8.7 Q16) but I am running into difficulties with rendering a path element.  Here is the command I am using:

```
convert svgtest2.svg svgtest2.png
```

and here is the content of my SVG file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="640" height="480">
  <path transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" fill="none" stroke="#E01B5D" d="M110,129 L180,342 L250,252 L390,67" stroke-width="2"></path>
</svg>
```

The resulting png should be pink lines with no fill, but I actually see a filled black triangle with no border.

What am I missing?  Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Comment: What version of Imagemagick are you using? I tried your command with ImageMagick 6.6.0-1 2010-03-03 Q16 and seems to work correctly: I see pink lines with no fill.

Comment: I edited my question to include this info: I'm using the latest 6.8.7-0 Q16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this question answered in a forum post at ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24263

I was able to solve my problem by specifying the opacities for the fill and stroke:

```
fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="1"
```